# create new file with system calls

Tags: c, posix, system-calls

Im trying to create a new file / overwrite an existing file using systemcalls 
, but  for some reason I have two problems:

1. When I'm first running the program it exits with value 0, so it seems 
 like it created the file successfully, but I can't see anything in my project directory.

 then when I secondly running the program the file is created, but an error message is printed on the screen.

2. Also after the first iteration of the program, I can't see the prinf message at the end of the main function.

Thanks for helping.

```
    int readFileDesc = 0, writeFiledesc = 0;
    int sourceFile = 1, destFile = 2, bufferSize = 3, isOverwrite;

    if (argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("     ex1 [-f] SOURCE DEST BUFFER_SIZE");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Checking if -f [OP] is activated.
    isOverwrite = (strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0);

    if (isOverwrite) {
        sourceFile++;
        destFile++;
        bufferSize++;
    }

    //Opening the source file
    readFileDesc = open(argv[sourceFile], O_RDONLY);
    if (readFileDesc < 0) {
        perror("Unable to open source file for reading: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //opening the destination file

    if (!isOverwrite) {
        //Case we dont have the -f [op] so we create the file.
        writeFiledesc = open(argv[destFile],
                O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_WRONLY ,
                S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if (writeFiledesc < 0) {
            perror("Unable to open destination file for reading: ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        //Case we have the -f [op] so we override existing file.
        writeFiledesc = open(argv[destFile], O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
        if (writeFiledesc < 0) {
            perror("Unable to open destination file for writing: ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    //Assume the buffersize is legal.
    bufferSize = atoi(argv[bufferSize]);
    char data[bufferSize];
    int nread, nwrite;
    while ((nread = read(readFileDesc, data, bufferSize)) > 0) {
        if ((nwrite = write(writeFiledesc, data, nread)) != nread) {
            printf("write problem: ");
        }
    }
// cant see this!
    printf("File %s was copied to %s" , argv[sourceFile] , argv[destFile]);
    //handling errors
    close(sourceFile);
    close(destFile);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: You mention "project directory", are you running your program from the command line or from inside an IDE or similar? What arguments are you passing to your program?

Comment: Also, if `read` or `write` returns `-1` (i.e. they fail) you don't have a check for that, perhaps you should add such a check and print a message in that case?

Comment: Im running the program in Eclipes , and the arguments are : -f [op for overwrite existing file] , sourceFilePath , targetFilePath , sizeOfBuffer.

Comment: If you're running in an IDE (like Eclipse), the programs default working directory might not be what you expect. You might want to configure it to make sure it is something expected. And what are the *actual* arguments you pass to the program, i.e. their *values*?

Comment: Lastly, have you tried stepping through the code using a debugger? And end your `printf` calls with a newline (`"\n"`), as that will flush the output buffer by default.

Comment: Well ending my code with newline doesn't  help. the weird thing is that after the second iteration I do see the file inside my project directory, but with an perror message on the screen.

Comment: first time you call with option -f, but there's no file to overwrite?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
    writeFiledesc = open(argv[destFile], O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
```

Using both `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY` is wrong.  You need to use `O_RDWR`.

Per [the POSIX standard for `open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Values for `oflag` are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags
>   from the following list, defined in . **Applications shall
>   specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes)
>   below** in the value of `oflag`:
>
> O_EXEC
>
> Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
>
> O_RDONLY
>
> Open for reading only.
>
> O_RDWR
>
> Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
>
> O_SEARCH
>
> Open directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a non-directory file.
>
> O_WRONLY
>
> Open for writing only.
>
> Any combination of the following may be used:
>
> ...

Also, `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.